# How to read values from Soap Request

Tags: php, xml, soap

I am interacting with Soap Web services and I would want to read the values from the soap object. I am getting an exception all the time. See below;

Sample soap;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <c2b:C2BPaymentValidationRequest xmlns:c2b="http://cps.huawei.com/cpsinterface/c2bpayment">
         <TransID>3IN40005PY</TransID>
         <TransTime>20160923143639</TransTime>
         <TransAmount>3000</TransAmount>
         <BusinessShortCode>10069</BusinessShortCode>
         <MSISDN>86812530102</MSISDN>
         <KYCInfo>
            <KYCName>FirstName</KYCName>
            <KYCValue>aaa</KYCValue>
         </KYCInfo>
         <KYCInfo>
            <KYCName>MiddleName</KYCName>
            <KYCValue>bbb</KYCValue>
         </KYCInfo>
         <KYCInfo>
            <KYCName>LastName</KYCName>
            <KYCValue>ccc</KYCValue>
         </KYCInfo>
      </c2b:C2BPaymentValidationRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I tried making an object

`$xml=simplexml_load_string($response) or die("Error: Cannot create object");`

So that I can read the values as below;

`$TransID=$xml->TransID;`
`$TransTime=$xml->TransTime;`
`$TransAmount=$xml->TransAmount;`

But it fails here **die("Error: Cannot create object");**

Or even better how can I change the soap request to json and get the values? Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems [namespace declaration (php manual)](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.registerxpathnamespace.php) for SOAP is missing in your code.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_data);
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('c2b', 'http://cps.huawei.com/cpsinterface/c2bpayment');
$response = $xml->xpath('//c2b:C2BPaymentValidationRequest')  or die("Error: Cannot create object");

print_r($response);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [TransID] => 3IN40005PY
            [TransTime] => 20160923143639
            [TransAmount] => 3000
            [BusinessShortCode] => 10069
            [MSISDN] => 86812530102
            [KYCInfo] => Array
                (
                    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [KYCName] => FirstName
                            [KYCValue] => aaa
                        )

                    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [KYCName] => MiddleName
                            [KYCValue] => bbb
                        )

                    [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [KYCName] => LastName
                            [KYCValue] => ccc
                        )

                )

        )

)
```